# Camera preview and AR items are not shown when navigating from another activity

Tags: android, camera, preview, augmented-reality, surfaceview

I'm trying to develop an AR application for training purposes.
There is a main activity that contains a FrameLayout with two views: the camera preview (a SurfaceView implementing the SurfaceHolder.Callback) and another custom surface for drawing a text over the camera preview.
This FrameLayout is created within MainActivity's onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    try{
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Panel for AR items
        **panelSurface = new PanelSurface(this);**

        WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = d.getWidth();
        int height = d.getHeight();
        panelSurface.setScreenSize(width, height);


        loadARItems();            

         //General frame
        FrameLayout rl = new FrameLayout(this);
         //Camera Surface
        **cv = new CustomCameraView(this);**
        rl.addView(cv, width, height);
        rl.addView(panelSurface, width, height);
        setContentView(rl);

        //Initialize sensors
        sensorMan = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
        locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating main activity: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If this activity is the first activity to be called: the camera preview is shown correctly with my AR Items over it.
Nevertheless, the problem appears when I come from another activity:
There is a menu activity that contains several buttons. One of this buttons will call to the Main Activity:

```
private OnClickListener mapListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);          
    }
};
```

When navigating from another activity, the camera is not shown!! The screen remains black.
And the AR items are drawn one time but aren't refreshed, they are drawn again painting all the screen whitout cleaning it before for showing the movement!

Why the same activity with the same code is not working correctly when it's called from another activity???

Debugging both scenarios I have checked:
When MainActivity is the first Activity, the log:
04-08 13:43:03.498: INFO/ActivityManager(85): Displayed activity com.lagunitacrew.activities/.MainActivity: 929 ms (total 929 ms) 
is shown before opening the camera.
However, in the second scenario, when the MainActivity is called from the Menu activity, this traced is written after opening the camera

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

When your activity goes to the background, do you try to destroy the current screen? I think that the problem is camera.open() function doesn't work when you go back. I suggest that you will write a function to destroy UI when the application goes to the background and call this function in onPause function.